# Setting a specific dnsentry

Tags: snow-leopard, dns

I have a server running at port 4433 on my localhost machine. I'd like to refer to the service as http://mytest.com:4433 from the browser or any script that I write. How could I set the DNS on OSX to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could add a new line in your `hosts` file (see man [hosts(5)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.6/man5/hosts.5.html)). The easiest that I know of would be to open a `Terminal` and use `nano` to edit the file. You could type this in your terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

(replace `nano` by `vi` if you are more familiar with the latter). Then go at the end of the file and add something like this:

```
127.0.0.1    mytest.com
```

Save the file (key combination for nano is (it's a o upper case): Ctrl + O).

The file `hosts` is read by mDNSResponder which is the local DNS cache on OS X (incl. Snow Leopard). So your browser will be redirected to the IP you set in the file.